# How do I add the DOMContentloaded event listener to the document in nextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, addeventlistener, domcontentloaded

I'm trying to add an html code snippet to my nextjs project. The code snippet contains external script which has a createButton function.

```
<div id="examplebtn"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      createButton('Name', 'Phone');
    });
    //]]>
  </script>
  <script src="https://example.com.na/js/example.js"></script>
```

The createButton function renders a button identified by the id (examplebtn in this case) and in a native html document it works fine. However, in nextjs I am unable to add an event listener to the DOMContentLoaded event as is shown in the script, for it to run the function once the DOM has been loaded. I have tried using Next/Script, useEffect hooks, native html tags all to no avail. How can I add the DOMContentLoaded event listener to the jsx component before the document is completely loaded so the function can run at the appropriate time? Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

{EDIT}
I'm adding the final code of createButton for more clarity. It's been edited as I can't release the code due to contractual obligations, however it should prove helpful.

```
window
  .ButtonComponent({
    params,
    onPay: function (v, vn, a, r, e) {
      c = customFunct(moreParams);
      PopupComponent({
        params,
        onCancel: function () {
          console.log('called onCancel');
          // stuff here
        },
        onSubmit: function (r) {
          // stuff here
        },
      }).render('body');
    },
  })
  .render('#examplebtn');
```

Comment: Have you tried [Nexjts url imports](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#url-imports)?

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.

Comment: Did you try it with Next/Script [dangerouslySetInnerHtml option](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#afterinteractive)?

Comment: Going by the the docs looks like you can call the function inside dangerouslySetInnerHtml option

Comment: I've tried all these and they don't work. I've been studying the function and it seems it manipulates the DOM directly. I need to get a hold of the document before it loads because the function renders an element which is identified by the id. The components being rendered seem to only have the document object when readyState is 'complete'

Comment: See this discussion: [DOMContentLoaded Event listener](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36622)

Answer (score 1):

you can take reference from [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36622#discussioncomment-2673989)

This is tricky, because this event triggers very early...

You could do:

```
 <script
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
            });
    `,
                }}
            ></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <div id="examplebtn"></div>
  {    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      createButton('Name', 'Phone');
    });  
  }
```

just use block and write whatever the script you want to

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Both in useEffect, before the return statement (i'm using functional components) as well as in a native html script tag and the nextJS script tag. Unfortunately, due to contractual obligations, I cannot share the code of createButton, however it renders a body element and then renders a button identified by "examplebtn" in this case.